# Find the distribution of $Y$ given $p_{X}$ and $ p_{Y \mid X}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation

> Let $p$ be the probability that a coin shows heads after a person flips it once. A person keeps flipping the coin until it shows heads for the first time. Let $X$ be the number of flips for this to happen. The person then flips the coin another $X$ times. Let $Y$ be the number of times the coin shows heads in the latter series of flips.
>
> Find the distribution of $Y$.

This is my approach:

$p_{X}(x)=p (1-p)^{x-1}$ and $p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)={x \choose y}p^{y}(1-p)^{x-y}$, then:

$$p_{Y}(y)=\sum_{x} p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\cdot p_{X}(x)= \sum_{x=y}^{\infty}{x \choose y}p^{y}(1-p)^{x-y}\cdot p (1-p)^{x-1}= $$

$$= \sum_{x=y}^{\infty}{x \choose y}p^{y+1}(1-p)^{2x-y-1}=\left(\frac {p}{1-p}\right)^{y+1}\sum_{x=y}^{\infty} {x \choose y}(1-p)^{2x}$$

This is how far i can come. My questions are:

1. Have i done any mistakes so far? If not,
2. How can i evaluate that sum?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no mistakes in 1 (nice job!).

Under the convention that $\binom{x}{y}=0$ if $x<y$ define: $$f_y(r):=\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}\binom{x}{y}r^x$$

Then we have:$$f_{y+1}(r)+f_y(r)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}\binom{x}{y+1}r^x+\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}\binom{x}{y}r^x=$$$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}\binom{x+1}{y+1}r^x=r\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}\binom{x}{y+1}r^x=rf_{y+1}(r)$$

So that: $$f_{y+1}(r)=\frac{r}{1-r}f_{y}(r)$$

Combined with $f_0(r)=\frac{1}{1-r}$ that leads to:$$f_y(r)=\frac{r^y}{(1-r)^{y+1}}$$

Writing $q$ for $1-p$ we then find:$$p_Y(y)=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{y+1}f_y(q^2)$$
The working out of this I will leave up to you.

Comment: Just beautiful, thanks alot !!

Comment: You are very welcome